# Change height and slide down a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Upon clicking on a textarea, I need it to change the height of the textarea to 60px and slide down at the same time so it all looks like one smooth animation.

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6399/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="well">
      <textarea style="width:462px" placeholder="Comment..."></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks. :)

Comment: Down to the size of 60px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you need is called **[animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)** and is well documented.

Now for your fiddle, [I wrote the jQuery code](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6403/) that demonstration the animate method plus the focus() and blur() methods:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){

    var element = $('.well textarea');
    var orig_height = element.height();
    var new_height = 60;

    // onfocus event handler
    element.focus(function (){
        $(this).animate({height: new_height + 'px'});
    });
    // onblur event handler
    element.blur(function (){
        $(this).animate({height: orig_height + 'px'});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6402/)?

```
$('#comment').click(function() {

   $(this).css('height', '60px');

});
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the textarea actually slide down slowly instead of instantly?

Comment: Oh I see what you meant by that now. Yea, use animate. Change this.css to this.animate({ height: "60px"},1000); (sorry for the bad format I'm on my phone now) @Erik

Answer (score 0):

It works much better as an animate...

```
$("textarea").on('focus',function (e, ui) {
    $(this).animate({
        height: "60px"
    }, 1500);
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/MgcDU/6405/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#comment').click(function () {

   $(this).fadeIn(3000, function() {
      $(this).css('height', '60px');
   });


   $(this).focusout(function() {
      $(this).css('height', '20px');
   }); 



});
```